# Code First EF6 Self Referencing Many-To-Many Throws Stack Overflow Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, stack-overflow, self-reference

I'm getting a stack overflow error when trying to find a user with the setup below. I've tried turning off both Lazy Loading and Proxy Creation, but I'm still getting the error.

```
public class Authority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AuthorityTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Authority> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The on Model Creating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Authority>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.Groups)
                    .WithMany().
                    Map(m =>
                        {
                            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                            m.MapRightKey("GroupId");
                            m.ToTable("UsersGroups");
                        }
                    );

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

The context constructor:

```
public Context()
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
}
```

This is the code that throws the stack overflow:

```
var byUserAndDomain = db.Authorities
                        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == AuthorityTypeEnum.User && a.Domain == MvcApplication.Domain && a.Name == MvcApplication.UserName);
```

Comment: I just replaced MvcApplication.Domain and MvcApplication.UserName with constants and I'm still getting the same stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Though the error was being thrown on the line with the Linq expression, the recursion was occurring in an external scope. I guess the entity frame has the lowest tolerance for recursion of the objects I'm working with.